# How to save the records from a file into table with certain order

Tags: java, file

Assume there are following records in a file:

### name score grade

### Alan  95    A

### Ram   80    B

### Bill  100   A

### Pale  81    B

Jon   63    C

Now I want to read the records from the file and save them to the DB one by one using Java, but the order will be: The record(s) with "A" grade will be saved to DB first, then "B" grade, then "C" grade.

How to do that?

Comment: read file, sort by grade, write to db? What's your actual problem?

Comment: Seems from comments that you do not know how to do any part of that.  Voting to close as 'overly broad'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be write Class with getter/setter for all properties (name, score, grade)

Read the file and create instance for the each record

Add a comparator  to sort them based on "Grade"

Then insert them into database.

Comment: Sounds great, then how should I read the records in the file to the class with getter/setter?

Comment: You need to use either BufferedStreams/FileStreams.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own mini parser. Read in the text,store it in a `String`. Read from the start, and keep reading till you encounter a grade, and then split accordingly, and based on the grade, insert that into your db. I don't think providing a snippet would be appropriate for this question , seems like a homework.